# Why isn't factory_girl operating transactionally for me? - rows remain in database after tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm trying to use factory_girl to create a "user" factory (with RSpec) however it doesn't seem to be operating transactionally and is apparently failing because of remnant data from previous tests in the test database.

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                   "Joe Blow"
  user.email                  "joe@blow.com" 
  user.password               'password'
  user.password_confirmation  'password'
end

@user = Factory.create(:user)
```

Running the first set of tests is fine:

```
spec spec/ 


...
Finished in 2.758806 seconds

60 examples, 0 failures, 11 pending
```

All good and as expected, however running the tests again:

```
spec spec/ 
...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1102:in `save_without_dirty!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:87:in `save_without_transactions!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.2.3/lib/factory_girl/proxy/create.rb:6:in `result'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.2.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:316:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.2.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:260:in `create'
    from /Users/petenixey/Rails_apps/resample/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:183:in `module_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:183:in `subclass'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:55:in `describe'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_factory.rb:31:in `create_example_group'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/dsl/main.rb:28:in `describe'
    from /Users/petenixey/Rails_apps/resample/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:133:in `run_examples'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec:5
    from /usr/bin/spec:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/spec:19
```

**Fix attempt - use Factory.sequence**

Since I have a uniqueness constraint on my email field I attempted to fix the problem by using the sequence method of factory_girl:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                   "Joe Blow"
  user.sequence(:email) {|n| "joe#{n}@blow.com" }
  user.password               'password'
  user.password_confirmation  'password'
end
```

I then ran

```
rake db:test:prepare
spec spec/
.. # running the tests once executes fine
spec spec/
.. # running them the second time produces the same set of errors as before
```

**Users seem to remain in the database**

If I look at the /db/test.sqlite3 database it seems that the row for the test user is not being rolled back from the database between tests. I thought that these tests were supposed to be transactional but they don't seem to be so for me.

This would explain why the test runs correctly the first time (and if I clear the database) but fails the second time.

**Can anyone explain what I should change to ensure that the tests run transactionally?**

Comment: Can I suggest that remove mentions of factory-girl in the question & tag? Since the core issue really is all about creating records in the wrong block. Same can happen if a record is created by the build-in create() call.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Finally fixed this and I hope I can save someone the six hours of debugging it took me to figure it out.

By a) getting lucky and ending up with a version of code that worked and b) stripping both sets of code down this is what I found:

**Test that chokes up**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  @user = Factory.create(:user) 
end
```

**Test that works**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  it "should make a factory models without choking" do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)   
  end
end
```

The transaction is defined by the ***it "should do something" do...*** statement. If you instantiate the factory outside that statement it turns out not to be transactional.

**You can also put it outside the "it should.." block as long as it's in a "before..end" block**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user) 
  end

  it 'should make a factory without choking' do
    puts @user.name
    # prints out the correnct name for the user
  end
end
```

On experimenting, it seems to be valid to define a user outside of an "it should do..end" block as long as it's in a "before.. end" block. I guess this is only executed in the scope of the "it should do..end" block and therefore works fine.

[Thanks to @jdl for his (also correct) suggestion]

Comment: any idea on how this behaves inside a let ? like so: let(:something) {Factory(:something)}

Comment: Very helpful, thanks Peter. Cezar, re. `let(:foo) {Factory(:foo)}`, it seems that `foo` will be created (the factory invoked) when first referenced, so it's the reference to foo that must appear inside an example or a `before` block.  The DB is still rolled back at the end of the example.

Comment: You can also use `let!` if you want foo to be created immediately. (And yes, that does work with transactions.)

Comment: Thanks MarkBerry and Ajedi32, I was wondering why let wasn't persisting my machinist Foo.make! to the db, but putting it in a before block did.

Comment: Never create any variables you want to test against outside an it, before, or let block. Assigning variables you want to test against (as in your first example) is a total no-no. The reason for this is that transactional test runs are very picky, and run setup & tear down every time EACH TEST IS RUN. This is a good thing because it means you have a clean database. What you're doing in 1st example is a no-no (obviously doesn't work) because it creates those objects when the FILE LOADS (literally when ruby reads the 'describe' block) which is only once at the start of all tests.

Comment: If you really want objects created globally before every test, see "Global after and before blocks" section here http://old.rspec.info/documentation/before_and_after.html

Comment: Watch your `all`s and `each`es, people! I was experiencing the same bug, except I had my `create` call in a global before block—thinking I was safe—as @jason-fb suggests. Unfortunately, changing the block to a `before(:each)` was the solution.

Comment: yea that was two years ago I barely remember that haha. @mklbtz -- just use database_cleaner and prefer the before(:each). I only use before(:all) when there are no alternatives and typically for non-data related stuff (like writing files to disk)

Comment: I have also noticed that the `before` block has to be a `before(:each)` block. Seems that models instantiated in a `before(:all)` get kept.

Answer (score 21):

See my blog entry on the difference between using `before :all` and `before :each` with regard to transactions: http://mwilden.blogspot.com/2010/11/beware-of-rspecs-before-all.html. In a nutshell, `before :all` is not transactional, and data created there will stick around after the test is run.

Comment: An important distinction, thanks for that clarification. Checking test.log, it appears that the `before :all` still starts a transaction (`BEGIN`), but then it runs a `COMMIT` rather than a `ROLLBACK`, which is why the data persists.

Answer (score 4):

In `spec/spec_helper.rb`, make sure you have the following

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

This seems to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Inside of `test/test_helper.rb` make sure that you have the following.

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  #...
end
```

Despite the name "fixtures" this works with `factory_girl` as well.

Comment: Even though it looks right,  that doesn't seem to fix the problem. I'm working through Michael Hartl's RailsTutorial and doing a second writing of the code he originally wrote. 

When I copied it word-for-word it all worked fine and I know that I never added the user_transactional_fixtures flag. Now though for some reason it's failing on the rewrite project even if I add that.

Comment: Commenting here because I too saw the same puzzling behavior.  Otherwise, the tuorial was awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into these same symptoms when upgrading a project from Rails 3 to Rails 4.  I had done a bundle install, and development mode seemed to be working fine, but I wouldn't get transactional behavior in tests.  It turns out doing a **bundle update** solved the problem.

Comment: Any idea which gems you updated during that `bundle update`?