# Getting duplicate items when mocking using RSpec and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

When using factory girl and RSpec to test my controller, I'm getting the error:

```
Failures:

  1) ProductsController Handling POST for create should redirect to products after success
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(products_path)
        Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
```

Based on the log file, it looks like the object already exists in the DB (and doesn't meet the redirect clause in the controller), which raises two questions:

1. Why aren't the calls getting mocked/stubbed?
2. What would a workaround be if I wanted to hit the DB? Using `@params =  FactoryGirl.build(:product).attributes.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at)` doesn't work either.

Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

test.log:

```
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"product"=>{"name"=>"Fruit Mania", "description"=>"The mania that is taking over the planet!", "price"=>"9.99", "inventory"=>"1", "product_image"=>"#<File:0x00
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE LOWER("products"."name") = LOWER('Fruit Mania') LIMIT 1
```

products_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe ProductsController, "Handling POST for create" do
  def sign_in_user
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user, @user
  end

  def do_post
    post :create, :product => @params
  end

  before do
    @product = mock_model(Product, :save=> true)
    Product.stub!(:create).and_return(@product)
    @params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product)
  end

  it "should redirect to products after success" do 
     sign_in_user
     do_post
     pending "need to figure out why redirect fails"
     response.should redirect_to(products_path)
  end
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name "Fruit Mania"
    description "The mania that is taking over the planet!"
    price "9.99"
    inventory 1
    product_image { File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'uploads', '1000x450.jpeg')) }
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
 def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    if !@product.valid?
      flash.now[:error] = ("The product was not added: <br><li>" + @product.errors.full_messages.join("<li>")).html_safe
      render "new"
    else
      if @product.save
        redirect_to products_path, :notice => "Product created successfully!"
      else
        flash.now[:error] = ("There were issues adding the product to the database. Please retry")
        render "new"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You're stubbing `create` but calling `new`. Check the validation errors to see why the save is failing in the using the db case

Comment: There aren't any validation errors. It's failing because the product already exists (which led to the two questions I asked at the top, why does it already exist and why is it even hitting the DB?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you why the database call is happening in the first place.

You should replace this line:

```
Product.stub!(:create).and_return(@product)
```

with:

```
Product.any_instance.stub!(:save).and_return(true)
```

You are stubbing the class method `Product::create`, but you really need to stub the instance method `Product#save`.

I suppose the following would also work:

```
Product.stub!(:new).and_return(@product)
@product.stub(:save).and_return(true)
```

Because of the failure to `save` you go through the `render` path which gives an HTTP response of 200, not the 302 you were expecting.

As to why it's hitting the database, I'm afraid I can't say why the model already exists from the given context. If you only run this single test, does it work? Try checking out this question for more ideas:

[Why isn't factory_girl operating transactionally for me? - rows remain in database after tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497135/why-isnt-factory-girl-operating-transactionally-for-me-rows-remain-in-databa/3498959#3498959)

I hope that helps.